# Editing the original variable after making a reference to it

Tags: python

```py
check1 = False
check2 = False

if x == y:
    sending = check1
elif x == z:
    sending = check2

if something is True:
    if sending is False: #actually checks if check1 or check2 is False
        do_stuff()
        sending = True #1 - want to change the actual variable ( check1 or check2 )
        await ask_for_confirmation()
    else:
        return
```

I make a reference to `check1` or `check2` depending on some other variables, after that if the chosen one is `False` i `do_stuff()` and `ask_for_confirmation()`, and  want to change that particular chosen one to `True` so it doesn't `do_stuff()` again ( confirmation runs the whole thing again ).

I know i can just check the variables again like that:

```py
check1 = False
check2 = False

if x == y:
    sending = check1
elif x == z:
    sending = check2

if something is True:
    if sending is False:
        do_stuff()
        if x == y:
            check1 = True
        elif x == z:
            check2 = True
        await ask_for_confirmation()
    else:
        return
```

But that seems like lots of unnecessary code and i feel like there's a better way to do that. Is there a way i can change the original variable with the reference? ( see #1 in the upper code )

Comment: Not elegantly. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but probably just use a dict or object. Usually, if you find yourself in a weird situation like this, your code probably has deeper design problems. Booleans aren't really great to have a lot of, better design uses data structures and functions to return truthiness values to represent state implicitly.

Comment: @ggorlen haha yes it probably does but that's the best solution i came up with : D It could be done with just one check instead of 2 but this way they're seperated, so they can work independently. `if x== y` it does check1, then `if x == z` will also `do_stuff()` haha, probably not the best explanation but i hope you get it

Comment: If you could provide a bit more context and less pseudocode someone can probably help fix potential underlying issues. See [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Sure, the existing answer helps you get Y done but doing "booleans by reference" with `wrapper[0]` is not something that will pass a code review and should raise all sorts of alarms.

Comment: @ggorlen Ahh i get you... It's just that i'm very "protective" of my own code for some reasons ( i shared a code with some friends, they stole it and made some money off of it ). I know  it's dumb but that's how i feel, don't want to share the actual problem but want to get it fixed... i know it's very hypocritical, especially because i copy paste code from others all the time. Still, i just feel like this is something too specific and people will steal my solution... i know i'm dumb, sorry again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that when you reassign `sending`, you're just pointing it at a different value, rather than modifying the value that it previously pointed to.

What you want to do is put your two `check` values into a mutable container, e.g. a list, and then modify that list.

```
checks = [False, False]

if x == y:
    sending = 0
elif x == z:
    sending = 1
# else:
#     sending = ???

if something:
    if checks[sending]:
        return
    do_stuff()
    checks[sending] = True
    await ask_for_confirmation()
```

or put each into its own mutable container (you still need to subscript the container to access or modify the value it contains):

```
check1 = [False]
check2 = [False]

if x == y:
    sending = check1
elif x == z:
    sending = check2
# else:
#     sending = ???

if something:
    if sending[0]:
        return
    do_stuff()
    sending[0] = True
    await ask_for_confirmation()
```

Comment: Thank you! will try it out!

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you, really appreciate it! I've used the 2nd one